# Show that the product of 2 elements in a field is only 0, if one of the factors is 0

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose a field $Z$ and $2$ elements of the field $a,b$.
Proof that $a*b = 0$ only if either $a$ or $b$ is $0$.

Comment: Hint: Who are the zero divisor in any field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It follows from the existence of inverses. If $ab = 0$ and $a \ne 0$, then $a$ has an inverse... so $b = (a^{-1}a)b = a^{-1}(ab) = a^{-1}.0 = 0$

Comment: in the last statement $= a^{-1}.0 = 0$
according to which rule b is replaced with 0?

Comment: $ab$ is replaced with $0$ since we assumed that $ab = 0$